# Auto increase number width between minitoc chapter number and title

Tags: minitoc

When the number of sections and subsections goes into the double digits the chapter number and title in the `minitoc` start to overlap:
[image]

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{minitoc}

\setcounter{chapter}{9}
\begin{document}

\dominitoc% Initialization
\faketableofcontents

\chapter{bla}
\minitoc% Creating an actual minitoc

\section{One}
One
\section{One}
One
\section{One}
One
\section{One}
One
\section{One}
One
\section{One}
One
\section{One}
One
\section{One}
One
\section{One}
One
\section{One}
One
\section{One}
One
\subsection{One}
One
\subsection{One}
One
\subsection{One}
One
\subsection{One}
One
\subsection{One}
One
\subsection{One}
One
\subsection{One}
One
\subsection{One}
One
\subsection{One}
One
\subsection{One}
One
\subsection{One}
One

\end{document}
```

Any idea how to prevent this? Since I have a whole batch of documents like this it would be good to automate the width instead of applying a fixed width. Packages like `tocstyle` that offer settings like `tocindentauto` don't seem to affect `mintoc`.

Comment: This is actually rather a `\l@subsection` or `\l@section` issue, in my point of view.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see, `minitoc` does not provide settings for horizontal settings, i.e. the `numwidth` under concern here. This is either set within commands such as `\l@section` and `\l@subsection` etc or use `tocloft` to add some spacing to the `\cftsubsecnumwidth` length register.

(I am unsure whether `tocloft` and `minitoc` are always compatible!)

The `numwidth` box is to small here and must be extended, the indentation has no effect on the width of this box -- it just shifts the box (to the right, usually)

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{tocloft}

\addtolength{\cftsubsecnumwidth}{10pt}
\usepackage{minitoc}

\setcounter{chapter}{9}
\begin{document}

\dominitoc% Initialization
\faketableofcontents

\chapter{bla}
\minitoc% Creating an actual minitoc

\section{One}
One
\section{One}
One
\section{One}
One
\section{One}
One
\section{One}
One
\section{One}
One
\section{One}
One
\section{One}
One
\section{One}
One
\section{One}
One
\section{One}
One
\subsection{One}
One
\subsection{One}
One
\subsection{One}
One
\subsection{One}
One
\subsection{One}
One
\subsection{One}
One
\subsection{One}
One
\subsection{One}
One
\subsection{One}
One
\subsection{One}
One
\subsection{One}
One

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, is there anyway to auto indent rather than simply fixing the width to the widest known number of chapter numbers?

Comment: @ADarkDividedGem: This would require some testing of the width of the largest chapter number. `\addtolength` is normally a good way, better than `\setlength{...}`

Comment: And actually it's not the indent that causes the problem -- the numwidth is the problem. The indent just shifts the 'number' box to the right

Comment: Sorry wasn't familiar with the technical term but if no one can provide an automated way of increasing the number I will accept this as the answer and just pre-process the document counting the number of subsections to determine the width needed.

Comment: @ADarkDividedGem: It's possible, I think, but requires much more work. If you want to the total numbers of subsections you can apply `xassoccnt` (a package I've written), but it's more work to do